# Fedora Server 38 beta dnf error

Tags: fedora, dnf

After this night my dnf on Fedora 38 broken. Always when I try to install some package or run upgrade command i have output

```
Total                                                                                                                     685 kB/s | 1.2 MB     00:01     
Problem opening package avahi-glib-0.8-22.fc38.x86_64.rpm
Problem opening package avahi-libs-0.8-22.fc38.x86_64.rpm
Problem opening package cmake-3.26.3-1.fc38.x86_64.rpm
Problem opening package cmake-data-3.26.3-1.fc38.noarch.rpm
Problem opening package cmake-filesystem-3.26.3-1.fc38.x86_64.rpm
Problem opening package cmake-rpm-macros-3.26.3-1.fc38.noarch.rpm
Problem opening package dnsmasq-2.89-2.fc38.x86_64.rpm
Problem opening package firewalld-1.3.1-1.fc38.noarch.rpm
Problem opening package firewalld-filesystem-1.3.1-1.fc38.noarch.rpm
Problem opening package grub2-common-2.06-95.fc38.noarch.rpm
Problem opening package grub2-pc-2.06-95.fc38.x86_64.rpm
Problem opening package grub2-pc-modules-2.06-95.fc38.noarch.rpm
Problem opening package grub2-tools-2.06-95.fc38.x86_64.rpm
Problem opening package grub2-tools-minimal-2.06-95.fc38.x86_64.rpm
Problem opening package gstreamer1-1.22.2-1.fc38.x86_64.rpm
Problem opening package gstreamer1-plugins-bad-free-1.22.2-1.fc38.x86_64.rpm
Problem opening package gstreamer1-plugins-base-1.22.2-1.fc38.x86_64.rpm
Problem opening package gstreamer1-plugins-good-1.22.2-1.fc38.x86_64.rpm
Problem opening package langpacks-core-en-3.0-32.fc38.noarch.rpm
Problem opening package langpacks-core-font-en-3.0-32.fc38.noarch.rpm
Problem opening package langpacks-core-font-ja-3.0-32.fc38.noarch.rpm
Problem opening package langpacks-core-font-uk-3.0-32.fc38.noarch.rpm
Problem opening package langpacks-core-ja-3.0-32.fc38.noarch.rpm
Problem opening package langpacks-core-uk-3.0-32.fc38.noarch.rpm
Problem opening package langpacks-en-3.0-32.fc38.noarch.rpm
Problem opening package langpacks-ja-3.0-32.fc38.noarch.rpm
Problem opening package langpacks-uk-3.0-32.fc38.noarch.rpm
Problem opening package libxml2-2.10.4-1.fc38.x86_64.rpm
Problem opening package polkit-122-3.fc38.1.x86_64.rpm
Problem opening package polkit-libs-122-3.fc38.1.x86_64.rpm
Problem opening package python3-firewall-1.3.1-1.fc38.noarch.rpm
Problem opening package python3-libxml2-2.10.4-1.fc38.x86_64.rpm
Problem opening package qt5-qtbase-5.15.9-1.fc38.x86_64.rpm
Problem opening package qt5-qtbase-common-5.15.9-1.fc38.noarch.rpm
The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.
You can remove cached packages by executing 'dnf clean packages'.
Error: GPG check FAILED
```

I'm trying `dnf clean all` but it didn't help. Also command `rpm -qa gpg-pubkey\*` return

```
error: rpmdbNextIterator: skipping h#      13 
Header V4 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID eb10b464: BAD
Header SHA256 digest: OK
Header SHA1 digest: OK
```

for all keys.

Answer (score 0):

If RPM isn't working, DNF won't work. I would start with rebuilding the RPM database: `rpm --rebuilddb`.